# UserDefaults swift 4

Tags: swift, dataset, nsuserdefaults

I have problems with UserDefaults.

```
import Foundation

class Utility: NSObject {
    func storeBaseDetail(firstname:String,lastname:String,picStr:String,email:String,usrname:String,user_Id:String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(firstname, forKey: "firstname")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(lastname, forKey: "lastname")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(picStr, forKey: "picStr")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(usrname, forKey: "usrname")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(user_Id, forKey: "id")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func getBaseDetail()->(firstName:String,lastName:String,picStr:String,email:String,usrname:String,user_Id:String){
        return ((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstname") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastname") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "picStr") as? String)!,(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "usrname") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "id") as! String))
    }

    func storeBaseDetail(firstname:String,lastname:String,picStr:String,email:String,usrname:String,user_Id:String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(firstname, forKey: "firstname")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(lastname, forKey: "lastname")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(picStr, forKey: "picStr")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(usrname, forKey: "usrname")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(user_Id, forKey: "id")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func getBaseDetail()->(firstName:String,lastName:String,picStr:String,email:String,usrname:String,user_Id:String){
        return ((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstname") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastname") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "picStr") as? String)!,(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "usrname") as! String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "id") as! String))
    }
}
```

If I call it UserDefaults:

```
if  Utility().getBaseDetail().firstName != ""{
    userNameLbl.text = "\(Utility().getBaseDetail().firstName) \(Utility().getBaseDetail().lastName)"
}
```

I get this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way to avoid nil values,

```
func getBaseDetail()->(firstName:String?,lastName:String?,picStr:String?,email:String?,usrname:String?,user_Id:String?){
    return ((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstname") as? String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastname") as? String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "picStr") as? String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email") as? String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "usrname") as? String),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "id") as? String))
  }
```

In other class create the instance of Utility,

```
  let utilityInstance = Utility()
```

then get your values by using if let,

```
if let emailValue = utilityInstance.getBaseDetail().email{
      print(emailValue)
    }
```

So, if the value is there then it will print, if there is no value then it will skip.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function with this

```
func getBaseDetail()->(firstName:String,lastName:String,picStr:String,email:String,usrname:String,user_Id:String){
    return ((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstname") as? String ?? ""),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastname") as? String ?? ""),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "picStr") as? String ?? ""),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email") as? String ?? ""),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "usrname") as? String ?? ""),(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "id") as? String ?? ""))
}
```